# How to fix this "'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns" error?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

This is the following error message I am receiving:

```
Error in predict.Arima(object, n.ahead = h) : 
  'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns
In addition: Warning message:
In forecast.Arima(leMod, xreg = myX) :
  xreg not required by this model, ignoring the provided regressors
```

when I try to run the following code:

```
library(forecast)
myX <- 1:100
myY <- myX + rnorm(100)
leMod <- arima(x = myY, 
               xreg = myX, 
              order = c(1,0,0), 
                 method = "ML", 
                 include.mean = T)
forecast(leMod, xreg = myX)
```

How do I fix it?

I would like to superimpose point predictions and prediction error bounds on top of a historical time series I have. I realize this is unconventional--typically people want predictions for future data--but this is indeed what I am after. Also, this question appears to have been asked over and over again on this site, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Is this the `forecast::` package? Please be explicit. (BTW: predictions are not always about the future ... they are a great way to validate models given historical "truth".)

Comment: @r2evans yes, it is. Let me add that line in. And yes, that's right about predictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. I vaguely remembered that `Arima` was a little better than `arima`, particularly when it comes to including intercepts and drifts and all that.

```
library(forecast)
myX <- matrix(1:100)
myY <- myX + rnorm(100)
myX <- cbind(1,myX)
leMod <- Arima(as.ts(myY), 
               xreg=myX, 
               order=c(1,0,0), 
               include.mean = F)
forecast(leMod, xreg = myX)
```